# Lookup for transporter locations in humans

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology

I am interested in several transporters and cotransporters (eg SLC12A1/2 and many others), more precicely, in (human) organism that are made of cells containing those transporters. So does anyone know a lookup table or database where I can find information about that? My google search unfortunately left me in the dark :/ So I am thankfull about any hint!

Comment: Welcome to Bio. It's unclear what information you are after; cell types? transporter proteins? What characteristics in the latter case you wish to know?

Comment: It seems to me like the OP just wants a database of all the types of transporters (especially proteins as he mentions 'cells') to get information about them.

Comment: Ah, sorry if my question wasnt clear... Basically I am looking for a database containing the transporter proteins linked with a list of human organisms where they occure. For example the transporter NKCC1(resp SLC12A1)  would be linked with the Inner ear, sensory neurons, the distal colon, salivary gland epithelial celss, etc... 
So I would be happy about anything like, or just similar to this  :)

Answer (score 1):

This site can help you locate RNA expression of a particular gene (if you know the gene for the protein in context) in various tissues. Its called biogps.
http://biogps.org/#goto=welcome

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Cool, this already is a good step forward :)

Comment: Update: So yes, the source helps a lot! Also I found another similar source which seems very nice: the EMBL-EBI expression atlas. 
Just one confusing thing I don't understand about either of the sources: I cannot find any gene expressions for the inner ear, corti, or cochlea... Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Haha! I got no clue. I don't use these stuff. All I knew is, while i look up proteins and all on wiki, it shows up this colorful bargraph on the right. Which happens to be an RNA expression thing from the site. I just pasted the link :)

Comment: BioGPS and related sites stem from research projects where RNA from a number of tissues and cell types are obtained, and (relative) mRNA abundances were measured (using microarrays or RNA-sequencing). See literature references on these sites for the primary papers. But not all tissues are easy to get enough RNA to measure accurately; cochlea would be a very small amount of material. Also they may not have found anyone willing to part with their inner ear for the sake of research ...

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot! thanks for that explanation :)